# Using JMESPath, filter array elements based on length of an array-valued property

Tags: jmespath

Given an input like this:

```json
[
  {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  },
  {
    "a": "bar",
    "b": [ ]
  },
  {
    "a": "baz",
    "b": [ 2 ]
  }
]
```

I want to filter out the elements that have a zero-length array for their `b` property to give:

```json
[
  {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  },
  {
    "a": "baz",
    "b": [ 2 ]
  }
]
```

How do I do this with JMESPath?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
[?length(b)>'0']
```

Comment: That certainly looks more intuitive!

Comment: `[?length(b) > 0]`, even. No need to create possible side effects by comparing a number [`number length(string|array|object $subject)
`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#length) to a litteral.

Comment: Using number caused some errors for me when using JMESPath in JSON beautifier Chrome extension. But certainly if it works it is preffered.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, simple in the end although the function name is a little misleading. All you need is this:

```
[?not_null(b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extendind @Dominik Brázdil answer, was able to achieve following in aws cli command.

**Note** : Double quotes `"` did not work, use single quotes `'`

```
aws apigateway get-usage-plans --query 'items[?length(apiStages[])>`0`].id' --max-items 5 --profile TPaaSProd
```

If you want to query json items whose specific particular value is empty or length is zero (0).

```
aws apigateway get-usage-plans --query 'items[?length(apiStages[])==`0`].id' --max-items 5 --profile TPaaSProd
```